# Retagging and burnination plan for the [social-politics] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

This is based on the previous Meta question: [What is the tag "social-politics" about?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4112/26455)

I have reviewed 35 questions for retagging. Tag changes are noted with a "+" or "-" depending on the action. Editing for spelling, grammar, punctuation, etc., will be done at the same time. Only one or two questions will be edited each day. Suggestions or objections to the plan may be noted in comments or as answers.

One post (# 4) has the lone tag [social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) so *burnination* should not occur until that post is retagged.

1. [Hamas' military spending](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/83347/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[weapons](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)

2. [Which pro-Russian movements or parties are still left in unoccupied Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79609/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

3. [Who has first or most famously distinguished different stages of social movements?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/77047/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[political-theory](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-theory)

4. [What are the political causes of social conflict?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/73683/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[society](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society)

5. [Checks and Balances on News Medias](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/64486/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

6. [Why does it seem that social issues overtaking fiscal issues in the USA when it comes to vote choice?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/63707/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

7. [How can a ban on people gathering be enforced when it is imposed for an epidemic?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/51052/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[public-health](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-health)

8. [In terms of US politics, has protecting taxicab operations from competition been a left-wing policy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47050/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

9. [What happens if the President of Chile resigns?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/46895/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[succession](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/succession)

10. [Is the social contract invalid if I change jurisdiction? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/44331/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

11. [Think tanks and newspapers that are associated with Macron's En Marche and pan-European Renaissance?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/41390/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[reference-request](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)

12. [The ethics on darwinism and social darwinism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/37849/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[reference-request](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request)

13. [Why does the government pose a Ban on things which have not been Scientifically proven to harm us? [duplicate]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/34740/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy)

14. [Famous European Member of Cabinet "Bridge-Builder"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33517/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[europe](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) +[cabinet](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cabinet)

15. [Who are the homeless](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/32068/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) -[social-welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-welfare) +[housing](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/housing) +[social-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-policy)

16. [What is the minimum age before your political views are considered well thought out and educated? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/31485/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) -[voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) -[political-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-system)

17. [Is there a feasible route by which UK housing can be made more affordable without devastating the housebuilding sector and its employees?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/28250/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

18. [Are there any societies/nations that use Torah laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27977/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government)

19. [Are there political answers to AI-induced mass unemployment? [duplicate]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27745/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[employment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) +[technology](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)

20. [What is the term for the idea that everyone should vote according to their own best interests? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25647/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting)

21. [What motives do those supporting gun control assign to the NRA?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/24804/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

22. [How to measure equivalency- the David vs Goliath problem [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/24544/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[society](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society) +[measurement](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurement)

23. [Does any legislation permit three or more legal parents?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/16177/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) -[policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policy) +[social-policy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-policy) +[law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law)

24. [If authoritarian regimes are so bad, why do we see so many of them?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13576/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[authoritarianism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authoritarianism)

25. [Why religious fractionalization index of Turkey so low given %20 percent of Alevi existance?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13540/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[indicators](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indicators)

26. [What policies exist to help elderly homeless people with serious mental disabilities?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12878/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[social-welfare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-welfare)

27. [Book recommendations: What social/political structures are humans inclined to form? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12031/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[political-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-system) +[society](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society)

28. [Do people who self-identify with the term 'social justice' tend towards respect for the individual or for the collective?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11077/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) -[political-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-system) +[social-justice](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-justice)

29. [Who are the key individuals in Canada's Old Age Security program?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10942/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[social-security](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-security)

30. [How can a classless society exist with religion](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10485/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) +[social-class](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-class)

31. [Can providing a basic income to a subset of poor citizens benefit the government politically?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9812/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

32. [How many people are in favor of legalizing marijuana, but have no intention of ever smoking it?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9391/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

33. [What is ISIS fighting for?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8983/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) -[government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government)

34. [In which case is separatism considered legitimate?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8592/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) -[geopolitics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geopolitics)

35. [How does the US justify its relationship with Saudi Arabia?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8524/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) -[geopolitics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geopolitics) +[international-relations](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-relations)

Comment: The re-tagging is complete and the tag is no longer present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nine questions remain for retagging for which I found only the removal of the [social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics) tag applies. If "burnination" will remove those tags, then all that remains is to check for possible editing.

[Original numbering retained.]

2. [Which pro-Russian movements or parties are still left in unoccupied Ukraine?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/79609/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

5. [Checks and Balances on News Medias](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/64486/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

6. [Why does it seem that social issues overtaking fiscal issues in the USA when it comes to vote choice?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/63707/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

8. [In terms of US politics, has protecting taxicab operations from competition been a left-wing policy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47050/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

10. [Is the social contract invalid if I change jurisdiction? [closed]](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/44331/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

17. [Is there a feasible route by which UK housing can be made more affordable without devastating the housebuilding sector and its employees?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/28250/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

21. [What motives do those supporting gun control assign to the NRA?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/24804/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

31. [Can providing a basic income to a subset of poor citizens benefit the government politically?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9812/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)

32. [How many people are in favor of legalizing marijuana, but have no intention of ever smoking it?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9391/26455)

-[social-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-politics)